# Closed-form expressions for nth composition of a function

Tags: functions, summation

Is there any general methods to find a closed-form expression for nth composition of a function?
(Any book/article recommendations?)

For example

Let $f(x)=1+2x$, we have:

$$g_1=f=1+2x$$

$$g_2=f\circ f=1+2(1+2x)$$

$$\vdots$$

$$g_n=f \underbrace{\circ...\circ f}_{\text{n times}}=\underbrace{1+2(...(1+2x))}_{\text{n times}}$$

$$\text{where $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and n$\neq0$}$$

Based on guess and check I got:
\begin{align}
g_n(x)
& =(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}2^k)+2^nx+1
\\
& =2^n-2+2^nx+1
\\
& =2^{n}x+2^n-1
\end{align}

But it wouldn't always be easy to guess and check...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: No, I think this is largely a case by case basis type of problem

Comment: You may be interested in [tag:fractional-iteration], but in general, closed forms cannot be made, even for simple quadratics, and mind anything that grows exponentially will grow as fast as tetration in the number of iterations, i.e. it is very easy to form functions that *grow too fast* to have closed forms (or too slow).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are closed forms for

1. polynomials of degree $1$
2. powers of $x$
3. fractional linear transformations
4. Chebyshev polynomials

but for most functions there is no closed form.